# プリロードで定義したAPIの結果がPromiseオブジェクトで返ってくる

Tags: javascript, electron

初めて質問させていただきます。

現在、Electronを学習中です。
JavaScriptについても非同期通信周りは特に理解が浅く、様々な箇所で理解が不足していることをご了承ください。

表題の通り、プリロードに記載した処理をレンダラープロセス側で実行すると、
その処理結果がPromiseオブジェクトで返されます。
Promiseオブジェクトではなく、処理結果（PromiseResult）をそのまま受け取りたいのですが上手くいきません。

▼プリロード（preload.js）

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('mysqlAPI', {
    dbConnect: async () => await ipcRenderer.invoke('dbconnect'),
    dbDisconnect: async () => await ipcRenderer.invoke('dbdisconnect'),
    queryExecute: async (query, params) => await ipcRenderer.invoke('queryExecute', query, params),
});
```

目指す処理としては、メインプロセス側でmysql2パッケージを利用してMySQLサーバーにSELECTクエリを発行し
取得結果をレンダラープロセス側に返すことを目的としています。

まず、現時点で確認できていることは

- クエリ発行処理(queryExecute)は動作確認済み。目的のデータが取得できている
- レンダラープロセス側でwindow.mysqlAPI.queryExecute()を実行するとPromiseが返される

  - PromiseResultには取得結果が格納されているのをDeveloper Toolsで確認済

preload.jsのqueryExecute部のコードを以下のように変更すると
    `queryExecute: async (query, params) => {const res = await ipcRenderer.invoke('queryExecute', query, params); console.log(res); return res;},`
console.log(res)で出力されるのはPromiseオブジェクトではなく、取得結果であることを確認しました。

上記のことから、preload.jsを経由することでPromiseオブジェクトに格納されてレンダラープロセスに渡される、という認識でいますが、間違いないでしょうか。

preload.jsが怪しいとは思いますが、ここから先どうすればレンダラープロセス側にPromiseではなく
結果を直接返せるようになるかが分かりません。
どうかお力添えをいただけないでしょうか。
また、情報が不足している箇所などありましたらお申し付けください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

未確認ですが以下の様にしてはどうでしょうか？

```
queryExecute: async (query, params) => await ipcRenderer.invoke('queryExecute', query, params),

  ↓

queryExecute: (query, params) => ipcRenderer.invoke('queryExecute', query, params),
```

上記の様に変更して、呼び出し側で

```
const res = await window.mysqlAPI.queryExecute(a, b);
```

の様に呼び出せば行けそうな気がします。

Comment: ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます。レンダラー側でawaitをすることで解決しました。
お二つの回答どちらも同じほど有益でしたが、サンプルコードも記載していただけたこちらを回答として承認させていただきます。
お世話になりました。

Answer (score 0):

Electron は触ったこともないのですが、プロセス間通信が非同期で`Promise`が返ってくるのはごく自然で回避不可能な仕様に見えます。

レンダラープロセス側で `await` するのが最も簡単な対処じゃないでしょうか。